# I have this matrix mx and I am trying to write a for loop that will run throught the code and sum the columns and give me the answer [4 2 9]

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix `mx` and I'm trying to write a code that will loop through and add the columns down. I keep getting an error message. I'm not sure how to finish this

```
mx = [1 2 3;1 -1 5; 2 1 1]
[r c] = size(mx)
res = zeros(1,3)
s = 0
for i =1:r
for j=1:c
    res(i,j) =sum(mx(:,j))
end
end
```

Comment: `sum` will give you the answer directly with no loops. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

The vectorised form is the most efficient and the preferred form for Matlab code.

Also a semicolon would be needed in your line

```
res(i,j) = sum (mx(:,j))
```

to suppress the output at every computation.

Again, this is not the preferred way. Since you loop through res (1:3 and 1:3) your res, your result will have a 3x3 solution and I guess that is not what you want.

Getting back to the vectorised solution:

sum ( matrix ) -> sum by columns 
therefore

```
sum(mx)
```

would result in [ 4 2 9 ]

should you want the sum on the other dimension, you could use again sum, this way

```
sum(mx,2)
```

that creates the sum by rows (and I add it for completeness).

Please search for matlab vectorization and help sum, from the prompt.